# Get visual feedback on select in PySimpleGUI

Tags: pysimplegui

I have a PySimpleGUI Tree. When the user clicks on one of the items, a event is posted. I than download something from the main thread (which might take several seconds to arrive).

The problem is that the selection (inversion of text) in the tree view is not visible for some time (it actually becomes visible when I am finished with downloading and displaying the result).

I tried changing the value of the tree to the selection key, but that does not work.

```
window[event].update(value=values[event])
```

Is there a way to get visual feedback on the selection earlier?

Comment: It is caused by GUI not yet updated. Try to call `window.refresh()` before you download something from the main thread, or do it in other thread.

Comment: Using anorher threadis complicated, because another thread (even if not calling any GUI functions) must stop the garbage collection to prevent spurious errors. I will try refresh.

Comment: Refresh did solve the problem